# Convention on Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I know that there is two convenient for exterior derivative:

$$d\omega (X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}(X\omega(Y)-Y\omega(X)-\omega([X,Y])),$$
and
$$d\omega (X,Y)=X\omega(Y)-Y\omega(X)-\omega([X,Y]),$$
Maple uses the second version. Does there exist various version of Lie derivative or Lie bracket such as exterior derivative?

Comment: The first convention is consistent with the volume of the unit cube in $\Bbb R^n$'s being $1/n!$. Ugh. Lie bracket is defined in terms of flows, not exterior algebra, so no.

Comment: Thanks, why your comment don't write as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure I understand your question. In your expressions $d$ denotes the exterior derivative, not the Lie derivative. The latter is usually denoted by $\mathcal{L}_X$, where $X$ is a vector field on your manifold. If $X$ generates a one-parameter group $\varphi_t$, then by definition 
$$\mathcal{L}_X K = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{K-(\tilde{\phi_t})K}{t}$$
where $K$ is any tensor in the tensor algebra on $M$ and $\tilde{\varphi_t}$ is the extension of $\varphi_t$ to the tensor algebra on $M$. I am not aware of any particular convention on this definition.